# multiple document root for httpd conf file

Tags: linux, apache, document-root

In the following http-conf file how to add on more entry to add bugzilla

i.e, 123.21.1.21 goes to my website and 123.21.1.21/bugzilla is pointed to /opt/bugzilla

```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
     ServerName Domainspace
     </VirtualHost>
     <Location "/">
     </Location>
```

Comment: @Pekka:what is the change that i have to make to access in 123.21.1.21/bugzilla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just set bugzilla up the other day,  similar scenario.  Here is my httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.local

<VirtualHost  xxx.xxx.xxx.local>
  ServerName  xxx.xxx.xxx.local
  DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost  xxx.xxx.xxx.local>
  ServerName  xxx.xxx.xxx.local
  DocumentRoot "C:/bugzilla"
</VirtualHost>
```

followed by

```
Alias /bugzilla "C:\bugzilla"
<Directory "C:\bugzilla">
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Alias`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
 ServerName Domainspace
 Alias /bugzilla /opt/bugzilla
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks,i could not get that working.can u please let me know any links or docs to this..

Comment: my bugzilla directory is /opt/bugzilla-3.6 i specified exactly as told..and restarted apache

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered but this worked for me on macosx

```
Alias /otherwork "/Volumes/anothervolume/otherwork"
<Directory "/Volumes/anothervolume/otherwork">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    #more options here
</Directory>
```